# Is there a problem with port parameter on MacOS MySQL CLI?

Tags: mysql

I'm Mac user and I've recently installed MySQL CLI with Homebrew :

```
brew install mysql-client
```

Most of time I use it for classic connection on default MySQL port :

```
mysql -h hostname -P 3306 -uuser -p
```

And it works great !

Now I need to use it to connect on specific port :

```
mysql -h hostname -P 44000 -uuser -p
```

And I get the following message :

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'ip' (using password: NO)
```

I've tried with passing password in clear or using a config file but I got the same message. It seems that password isn't send when a port other than default is used.

Anyone has already encountered this problem and know how to solve it please ?

Comment: Does your MySQL instance is reconfigured for to use this non-standard port?

Comment: Yes the MySQL instance is configured for the non-standard port.
I think the problem comes from my Mac because I can connect on this instance from another server.

Comment: The very strange thing is that the error shows : "(using password: NO)" despite I enter a password.

Comment: Is there a local .ini file in this client? check client parameters section in it...

Comment: Can you add the version number of the client (and the server)?

Comment: Client version is : 
`Ver 8.0.18 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew)`
Server version is a little bit special because it's TiDB (NewSQL) but it's MySQL compliant : 
`Release Version: 3.0.7`

Comment: Did you `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` ?

Comment: I can connect on my instance from another client (but not Mac) so I think the problem is on Mac client when using another port than default.